# nodejs sendFile page rendering with an additional json

Tags: javascript, express

I would like to pass into the client - in addition to the html page a JSON

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build/index.html'), {aaa: "asdsadaod"});
```

so I'll be able to do something like this in the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>XXX</title>
     <script>
        const a = "{{aaa}}"
        alert(a)
     </script> 
  </head>
  <body>
     YYY
  </body>
</html>
```

is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sendFile` has no way to do that. It just sends a file.

Instead, pick a [template engine](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) and use [`res.render()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render).